# I can't find web3.eth.personal.newAccount

Tags: node.js, ethereum, blockchain, web3js, go-ethereum

[Geth client command]

```
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcvhosts=* --rpcport "8545" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,admin" --syncmode "light" --cache "64"
```

[node.js Web3 code]

```
var Web3 = require("web3");
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
web3.eth.personal.newAccount("test").then(console.log)
```

This is the error message I've got right below

> > TypeError: The latest parameter should be a function otherwise it
>   can't be as callback
>   at NewAccountMethod.set (C:\Users\june\Documents\WebProject\webWalletTest\node_modules\web3-core-method\dist\web3-core-method.cjs.js:411:17)
>       at Proxy.anonymousFunction (C:\Users\june\Documents\WebProject\webWalletTest\node_modules\web3-core-method\dist\web3-core-method.cjs.js:224:28)

I wanted to see a function "web3.eth.personal.newAccount". but I can't find the function.

Even I tried to find out with double tab (auto completion) but it didn't exist.

Was it gone?

Comment: Are you sure that's the error message? At the very least, it seems to be missing a word. Please copy/paste the actual error message.

Comment: I modified the part of error message.

Comment: Are you sure the actual error message isn't "The latest parameter should be a function otherwise it can't be used as callback"?

Comment: That's actual error message i've got. is it weird?

Comment: Yes, because at least the current version of that code has the error message I described. Perhaps you have an older version with a typo? What version of web3.js are you using?

Comment: it's 1.0.0-beta.40

Comment: I'm on 1.0.0-beta.41. Perhaps it was just changed? In any case, I can't reproduce the error (with any error message).

Comment: I'm gonna try on beta.41. but it's weird. As far as I know, 'newAccount' is very basic function and it's existed for a long time.

Comment: same problem, I'm using web3@1.0.0-beta.41 and Ganache CLI v6.3.0 (ganache-core: 2.4.0)

Comment: the problem is still going on 1.0.0-beta.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I used `web3.personal` directly and I was able to access the methods inside it again.

This is weird because in the console, `web3.eth.personal` is still what works but in the script for a browser, it doesn't.